# help with price update between two lists

Tags: excel

I need some help with an excel command.
I got two excel files, with about 600 products, the products are the same but with different order and different prices.

There is no actual order for the price list, the single problem is that if i mess up the order, it won't work on the web (SQL import).
How can I add the prices from second list to the first list without messing up the order?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the product names are unique or have some kind of unique identifier then you can replace the price in the “sorted” list with a vlookup function and have the real prices stored on a separate sheet which in the below example called I have called data “Data”.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Data!A1:B65536,2,FALSE)
```